# Different remote branches for pushing and pulling

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to `git push` to branch B, while using `git pull` to pull from branch A, while the local branch is branch C?

I realize that `git pull` pulls all the branches down by default, and would be fine with setting it up to only pull the currently checked out branch.

To clarify; the local clone of the repository only has branch C.

```
git fetch
git pull
```

For this branch get their commits from remote branch A and

```
git push
```

Should send commits upstream to remote branch B.

Comment: You can of course specify the remote and the branch to pull from and push to. `git pull <remote> <branch>`. But perhaps you are asking a different question?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to configure it so that I didn't need to specify the remote and branch each time. Hopefully without having an alias?

Comment: oops, added my answer before reading these comments. Christoph's answer below is probably better for you :-). As to me - I actually prefer explicicity of stating the branches, gives me sense of confidence of knowing exactly where things are going.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your command more explicitly - this would also ensure you know exactly where commits are coming from or going to.

`git push` (and `pull`) by default expand to `git push origin current_branch_name`, which is a shorthand for `git push origin current_branch_name:current_branch_name`, where left side of the colon is originating branch and right side is destination branch.

So, for your example, to pull from remote branch `A` to local branch `C`, you could do

`git pull origin A:C`

to push from local branch `C` to remote branch `B` -

`git push origin C:B`

Answer (score 0):

The `branch.<name>.pushRemote` option was created to simplify the use case you describe: pushing to a different remote than you pull from. The [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/config.txt) has more details.

Comment: Can this be used for changing the name of the branch as well?